# Delete/Remove a document from a collection using command prompt in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to remove or delete one or more documents from a collection in MongoDB without using MongoDB Compass.

How can I remove or delete a document using Command Prompt ?

I have create a db 'University' and a collection 'names'. 
On the collection 'names' I have create 8 documents the 5 are full with data and the rest 3 are with data that I don't want them on my collection. 
How I can remove those 3 document?

Comment: There is detailed description in the docs on how to connect from shell(command prompt), use database to work upon, and ops on collection of that db [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/). Is there something specific to that you are facing as problem.

Comment: I have create a db 'University' and a collection 'names'. 
On the collection 'names' I have create 8 documents the 5 are full with data and the 3 are with a data that I don't want them on my collection. 
How I can remove them ?

Comment: Is mongodb on your local system (localhost)??.. then just open command prompt 1. `mongo --port 27017` to connect to shell 2. `use University` 3.`show collections` will show you collections on the db, if you see a `names` collection.?

Comment: Yes I have created the db University & Collections names via command prompt. 
Yes I can see the the collection names

Comment: Okay! So to remove those 3 documents from `names` collection, you know ids of those documents right. Do as one of the answers. `db.names.deleteOne({_id: ObjectId('idofdoctodelete')})`. That you run 3 times for those 3 docs.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to mongo shell.

Run the following command

```
use db_name
db.getCollection(*collection_name*).deleteOne()
```

You can refer [mongoDb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) as well.